# ArrayAdapter does not update view when notifyDataSetChanged() is called

Tags: android, adapter, android-arrayadapter, auto-update

So I have a piece of code that look like this

```
    floorList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, floorList);
    arrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    floorSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    floorList.add("a");

    Call<ParkourResponse<ParkingPlaceResponseObject>> getPlaceDetailCall = Helper.getParkourService().getPlaceDetail(placeID);
    getPlaceDetailCall.enqueue(new Callback<ParkourResponse<ParkingPlaceResponseObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ParkourResponse<ParkingPlaceResponseObject>> call, Response<ParkourResponse<ParkingPlaceResponseObject>> response) {
            ParkingPlaceResponseObject placeDetail = response.body().getRespObject();
            Floor[] floorArray = placeDetail.getFloor();
            floorList.clear();
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(int i = 0; i < floorArray.length; i++){
                floorList.add(Integer.toString(floorArray[i].getNumber()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ParkourResponse<ParkingPlaceResponseObject>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

So when I tried to add "a" that is not part of the Retrofit service, the spinner is updated.

But everything that I do to floorList inside the onResponse() does not update the adapter and spinner.
I tried to clear it on the onResponse() and then call the notifyDataSetChanged(), even that does not delete the "a" option from the spinner.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: well `notifyDataSetChanged` shoudl be obviosuly called after changes are made ... also **you should not** relay on changing `ArrayList` which you pass to `ArrayAdapter` ... you should directly use methods of ArrayAdapter to remove/add items

Comment: it wont because you are making changes in your floorlist inside your onResponse. You have to update the list which is being used by adapter class. Better to make a method in your adapter and pass this list and call notifyDataSetChanged .

Comment: well I called it but the floorList is still not update, let alone the `add` inside the `onResponse()`, even the `floorList.clear()` does not clear the floorList array @Selvin

Comment: it may or may not (as I wrote **you should not** relay on changing ArrayList passed to constructor when you are working with ArrayAdapters ) ... take a look at ArrayAdapter source ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the comments by Selvin and Gautam while following this answer, as they are correct and will help you to understand why the code should look like the following:

```
floorList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, floorList);
arrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
floorSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
arrayAdapter.add("a"); //I would jsut pass this into the adapter's constructor

Call<ParkourResponse<ParkingPlaceResponseObject>> getPlaceDetailCall = Helper.getParkourService().getPlaceDetail(placeID);
getPlaceDetailCall.enqueue(new Callback<ParkourResponse<ParkingPlaceResponseObject>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ParkourResponse<ParkingPlaceResponseObject>> call, Response<ParkourResponse<ParkingPlaceResponseObject>> response) {
        ParkingPlaceResponseObject placeDetail = response.body().getRespObject();
        Floor[] floorArray = placeDetail.getFloor();
        arrayAdapter.clear(); //update the adapter, not the external list
        arrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false); //we'll only update after list is full, for efficiency
        for(int i = 0; i < floorArray.length; i++){
            arrayAdapter.add(Integer.toString(floorArray[i].getNumber()));
        }
        arrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ParkourResponse<ParkingPlaceResponseObject>> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I would rather mover `clear()` after `setNotifyOnChange(false)` ... also  there is no need for `notifyDataSetChanged()` after `setNotifyOnChange(true)` ... but as long as  `onResponse` would be called than it should works  ...

Comment: I double checked - setNotifyOnChange does not notifyDataSetChanged, at least on 25.

Clear could be moved after we stop the notifications but I left it earlier because we don't know how long running the loop will be. It's really down to OPs preference when he implements it

Comment: [you are right](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L328) ... I misunderstood
documentation: *if true, modifications to the list will automatically call notifyDataSetChanged()* modification ... not calling setNotifyOnChange itself with true

Comment: thanks. It turns out that the problem is with the custom spinner library that I used. When I used ListView, it just simply updated. Thanks for the answer and recommendation.